# How do I software trigger the barcode scanner of a handheld device?

Tags: c#, sdk, barcode, handheld

I am currently writing an application for Panasonic's TOUGHPAD FZ-E1 and I have problems software triggering the barcode scanner. I know this is possible because the demo app that came with it does that.
My code is written in C# according to the Microsoft documentation provided here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792056(v=winembedded.81).aspx[^]

The app crashes when I call this method:

```
private async void SoftwareTrigger_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (scanner.Capabilities.IsSoftwareTriggerSupported)
    {
        await claimedScanner.StartSoftwareTriggerAsync();
    }
}
```

The code compiles, but when I test it on device the app crashes saying that IsSoftwareTriggerSupported and StartSoftwareTriggerAsync() are not found. 
I carefully followed all the steps in the documentation and I don't think I missed something.

If someone has any idea how to achieve my goal please let me know.

Thank you,

Raul

Comment: I dont know what kind of scanner you are using, but normally a scaner works as akeyboard, it just send the scanned keys as if you would have typed them with a key board, then an enter, all you have to do i code for the key pressed event

Comment: Getting data from the scanner works fine. I have a button on the device that manually triggers the scanner to acquire data. The problem is that I need to trigger the scanner from my application. I know this is possible because the SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43677) gives me access to this capability, but at runtime the app acts like it is using a different assembly.

Comment: make sure you have handheld emulator install on your development machine. Also "Windows.Devices.PointOfService" is available in windows phone 8.1 object browser.

Answer (score 2):

I have received a response from Panasonic and as I suspected we will have to wait for an update.  Here is a quote from their email:
**"it looks like there is a limitation within the current WH8.1H
It will be fixed into the next coming version GDR2"**

So unfortunately, the solution is to wait for the update :(