# Barcode scanner in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, embedded, barcode

I have a problem with the development of an application in C#. Teng one phablet Panasonic FZ-E1 reader with integrated barcode. I need to access it. I searched and searched the internet but I have not found anything that can help.

Comment: I am developing an application through Cordova, which generates a Windows Phone project. There is no plugin to access the barcode in wp8. That's why I have to develop it. I found the capabiliti pointOfService for desktop applications, but is not compatible with Windows Phone 8. I can not find no examples or documentation on how to access the integrated bar code scanner (not through the camera).

Comment: On  Panasonic website I saw that the barcode reader is optional. Are you sure that your device has it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I software trigger the barcode scanner of a handheld device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386415/how-do-i-software-trigger-the-barcode-scanner-of-a-handheld-device)

Comment: this device has built-in barcode reader. What I find strange is that there is a sample application that if it is able to access the barcode scanner.

Comment: afaict, your device is a *laptop*.  Why the [tag:windows-phone-8] tag?

Comment: because the operating system is Windows Phone 8. He added this tag that maybe someone has had a similar problem in this version.

Comment: @JSOLER did you try to contact the app producer? Are you sure that the barcode, as on standard desktop, is not seen as a keyboard?

Comment: I contacted Panasonic. I got some links of reference, but the component that you use to access the barcode reader is pointOfService. This "according to Microsoft documentation" is not compatible with Windows Phone 8.
If I could add to my project pointOfService somehow I think it would be enough.
I spent the links are:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263092.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792060(v=winembedded.81).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.pointofservice.aspx

Comment: @JSOLER did you ever make any progress on this? I'm having the exact same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Wired USB barcode scanners are a problem for many phones. Most phones do not implement USB-on-the-go which enables them to be hosts or be the master in a USB transaction. Phones typically are devices that you connect to hosts/pcs. Ones that do sometimes don't have the power to drive the USB barcode scanner. The best option is to find a Bluetooth barcode reader, but ... This is a problem for Windows Phone which didn't put that driver in the stack (at least a few versions back when I looked.

Comment: I think that the OP problem is not to connect an external barcode reader, because of the  Panasonic FZ-E1 has an integrated barcode.